# Best lossless compressison algorithm for data with repeating strings

Tags: java, algorithm, object, compression

I have an object Aobj to compress which contains a list of Bobj objects.

```
Aobj = {
    someInt=123; someString = str;
    someList = [ 
       Bobj1 {key1=xyz,key2=345; };
       Bobj2 {key1=abc,key2=123; };
       Bobj3 {key1=dsd,key2=323; };
       ........
    ]
}
```

As we see this contains repetition of keywords key1,key2. What would be the best compression algorithm for the object Aobj?

Criteria -

1. Lowest time
2. Maximum compression ratio

The only thing I want to know is what are the varied compression formats that I can possibly use. 
The exact metrics around time taken and compression ratio achieved will be experimented upon once I have a handy list of what all algorithms work best for such objects.

Comment: Isn't [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) exactly this? Folding repeated strings into one code?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon yes I was looking at LZW as one of the options.  We currently use ZLIB for the compression, I was looking for any better options, or any abstarctions of LZW

Comment: (The most abstract form of compression that coder me can think of is [Kolmogorov compression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Compression). LZW is a *pointer compression* ("The macro model for data compression") as well as a [dictionary compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder).)

Comment: Best in what way? Speed? Compression ratio? Usually the answer to a "best" question is "Try it yourself and see." Are you willing to write your own, or rearrange the data format to increase the compression ratio? How much time are you willing to put into it? How much time will you allow the compressor to work? What is your target compression ratio? Unless you define your criteria, "best" is meaningless.

Comment: @JimMischel updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your criteria of lowest time and maximum compression are in conflict. So you will simply need to try a bunch of compressors and see what balance of time and compression ratio makes you happy. [lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4) will give really fast compression (and blazingly fast decompression), but not the best compression ratio. [zlib](http://zlib.net/) will give you a range of options, where time goes up and compressed size goes down from level 1 to level 9. [LZMA](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) will give you better compression, but will take longer and consume more memory.